# Why do firewall updates in Plesk/Linux take so long

Tags: linux, plesk

This is more a question of curiosity.

When I update the firewall rules using Plesk on a Linux vServer, the update takes 'very long'. Very long means 15-20 minutes until the necessary statements are generated and before they can actually be applied. Which is then done in reasonable time.

The server shows no load during the period to generate the statements.

The resulting list of FW-commands is not that extensive in my opinion: 1550 lines.

So as I said, it's not a big issue, it's just annoying and I am curious.

Any ideas, hints, explanations are welcome.

Comment: It seems that the run-time comes from the statement to list the ip6tables: /sbin/ip6tables -t filter -L which tries to resolve the hostnames. Adding a -n param (if possible) could reduce the run-time.